# Two styles of check return value in ksh

Tags: shell, ksh

In ksh shell, I wanna to check the return value after running a command, I've wrote two styles:

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    echo "failed!"
    exit 1
else
    exit 0
fi


[ $? -ne 0 ] && echo "failed!" && exit 1
```

Are they equivalent? If not, what could I do if I wanna to write it in one line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're close, but not the same.  First, the `if` will execute the `exit 1` even if the `echo` failed for some reason; the chained expression won't.  Also, the chained version lacks an equivalent of the `else exit 0`.

A better equivalent would be this:

```
[ $? -ne 0 ] && { echo "failed!"; exit 1; } || exit 0
```

This is tagged `ksh`, so you might find the numeric expression syntax cleaner:

```
(( $? )) && { echo "failed!"; exit 1; } || exit 0
```

But you can also write an `if` on one line, if you like:

```
if (( $? )); then echo "failed!"; exit 1; else exit 0; fi
```

If the command that you just ran above this expression in order to set `$?` is short, you may want to just use it directly as the `if` expression - with reversed clauses, since exit code 0 is true:

```
if grep -q "pattern" /some/filename; then exit 0; else echo "failed!"; exit 1; fi
```

It doesn't matter for this simple case, but in general you probably want to avoid `echo`.  Instead, use `printf` - or if you don't mind being ksh-only, you can use `print`. The problem with `echo` is that it doesn't provide a portable way to deal with weird strings in variables:

```
$ x=-n
$ echo "$x"
$
```

While both `printf` and `print` do:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$x"
-n
$ print - "$x"
-n
```

Again, not a problem here, or any time you're just printing out a literal string, but I found it was easier to train myself out of the `echo` habit entirely.

Comment: Why `print` is better than `echo` in ksh?

Comment: I edited to add an answer to that question.  I would actually recommend `printf` (in the modern versions of `ksh` which have it), because it's portable across shells.